# Extract data from list using a delimiter

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

I have a set of 10 python lists in the below format:

```
[ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH]
[PQR*RST*567>~AWS*999*POI]
[XYZ*TGT*234>~2352*245*HFT]
[STU*DEF*789>~654*345*QQQ]
```

I am trying to extract data from the above list such that the final output is a Dataframe and **expect the below output**:

```
123,999,HHH
AWS,999,POI
2352,245,HFT
654,345,QQQ
```

Given below is what I have done thus far:

```
allFiles = Path where all the txt files are stored
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    with open(file_) as fp:
        lines1 = fp.read().split('\n')
        b = [i.split('~', 1)[1] for i in lines1]
        print(b)
```

The above gives me a list as below:

```
[123*999*HHH]
[AWS*999*POI]
[2352*245*HFT]
[654*345*QQQ]
```

I am unable to extract the above data using a delimiter (*) and split them into different columns and have this saved to a Dataframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start by creating a dataframe with the lists of strings as rows and split each string by `~` using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). You can then slice the result selecting only the second term followed by another split, this time by `*`, setting `expand=True`:

```
l1 = ['ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH']
l2 = ['PQR*RST*567>~AWS*999*POI']
l3 = ['XYZ*TGT*234>~2352*245*HFT']
l4 = ['STU*DEF*789>~654*345*QQQ']

df = pd.DataFrame([l1,l2,l3,l4], columns=['col1'])
df.col1.str.split('~').str[1].str.split('*', expand=True)

     0    1    2
0   123  999  HHH
1   AWS  999  POI
2  2352  245  HFT
3   654  345  QQQ
```

---

**Update**

For doing the above with lists from multiple files:

```
l = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    f = open(file_, 'r')
    l.extend([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()])
```

And then do the same as before:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['col1'])
df.col1.str.split('~').str[1].str.split('*', expand=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however the number of lists is not fixed. It changes dynamically. How could I have the above work such that we don't have to define the number of lists.. Thanks.

Comment: @scottmartin how are your lists saved? In a larger list?

Comment: each file I read gets stored as a list. As shown in my initial post, I have 'n' lists as a result of my reading the files from a folder (where n is the number of files in the folder). Hope I have answered your question here.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you already have the lists, a simple function can split on delimiter(*).

```
l1 = ["123*999*HHH"]
l2 = ["AWS*999*POI"]
l3 = ["2352*245*HFT"]
l4 = ["654*345*QQQ"]

def split_delim(l):
    for i in l:
        l = i.split('*')
    return l

l1 = split_delim(l1)
l2 = split_delim(l2)
l3 = split_delim(l3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'l1':l1, 'l2':l2, 'l3':l3})
df
    l1      l2      l3
0   123     AWS     2352
1   999     999     245
2   HHH     POI     HFT
```

A more generalized solution that is independent of the number of lists. This performs all the split operations before forming the dataframe.

```
#allFiles = Path where all the txt files are stored

def split_delim(Files):  
    list_ = []
    for file_ in Files:
        with open(file_) as fp:
            lines1 = fp.read().split('\n')
            b = [i.split('~', 1)[1] for i in lines1]
            for i in b:
                l = i.split('*')
                list_.append(l)                
    return list_

list_new = split_delim(allFiles)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_new, columns=['col1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator `~`, and parameter `name`s and then add [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for second column for `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH
PQR*RST*567>~AWS*999*POI
XYZ*TGT*234>~2352*245*HFT
STU*DEF*789>~654*345*QQQ"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="~", names=['a','b'])

df = df['b'].str.split('*', expand=True)
print (df)
      0    1    2
0   123  999  HHH
1   AWS  999  POI
2  2352  245  HFT
3   654  345  QQQ
```

If want use your solution, add another `split`:

```
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
with open(file_) as fp:
    lines1 = fp.read().split('\n')
    b = [i.split('~', 1)[1].split('*') for i in lines1]
    list_.append(b)

df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in list_ for y in x])
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you . I added another line where in I saved the list to a Dataframe and see only the last list/ file gets saved.

`df = pd.DataFrame(b)`

Could you please assist. Thanks.

Comment: @scottmartin - Can you check now?

Comment: just another help. I have a few rows that have values such as 0001~ABC after performing the split as mentioned above. Could you please advice as to how could I modify the above code such that I can apply this additional split('~') method on the latest updated code you shared above..

Comment: @scottmartin - Better is create new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your delimiter explicitly, for example

```
print('ABC*DEF*123>~123*999*HHH'.split('~')[1].split('*'))
```

produces:

```
['123', '999', 'HHH']
```